# How to make an edit option for my ToDo List application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am new to React and I've been working on a simple To-do list with State Hooks. I am having trouble to make an edit option for it. When I am pushing the "Edit button" I want to go to the task and modify it, but I am completely clueless.

This is where the button is:

```html
import React from 'react';

function TodoList({ todo, index, toggleComplete, removeTodo, editTodo}) {
  
  function Checkbox() {
    toggleComplete(todo.index);
  }

  return (
    <div className="todo"> 
        <input type = "checkbox" onClick={Checkbox}/> 
          <div style={{textDecoration: todo.completed ? "line-through" : "" }} > 
              {todo.text}
          </div>
      <div>
        <button class = "button" onClick={() => editTodo(todo.text, todo.index)}>Edit Task</button>
        <button class = "button" onClick={() => removeTodo(index)}>Delete Task</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  );
}

export default TodoList;
```

This is a part of App.js with my broken editTodo function:

```html
function App() {
  
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
  
  const editTodo = (text, index) => {
    setTodos(
      todos.map(todo => {
        if(todo.index === index){
          console.log(todo.text);
          todo.text = text;   
          console.log(todo.text);
        };
        return todo;
      }))
  }
  
   return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="todo-list">
        <h3 class="title is-3" style={{textAlign: "center"}}>To-do list</h3>
          <TodoForm addTodo={addTodo} clearList={clearList} />
            {todos.map((todo, index) => (
              <TodoList
                key = {index}
                index = {index}
                todo = {todo}
                toggleComplete = {toggleComplete}
                removeTodo = {removeTodo}
                editTodo = {editTodo}
              />
            ))}      
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

  export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

Well You have done most of it, only changing the state remains.

As You have already used `map` I would suggest smth like this

Note: I assume that Your todo object looks like this

```
{
  index: 1 
  text: "string"
}
```

```
const editTodo = (text, index) => {
    setTodos(
      todos.map(todo => {
        if(todo.index === index){
          return {...todo, text}
        };
        return todo;
      }))
  }
```

Comment: My object looks like this: const [value, setValue] = useState([]);

Comment: And when I want to check a box or edit an item from my todo list, it applies to all my items in the list and I don't understand why.